# org-sbe returns #ERROR

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am new to org-mode.  I have just installed the latest version using el-get, but I am having a very annoying problem.
The command org-sbe doesn't seem to work.
Here is a minimal example that I took from the doc:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
  (defun fibbd (n) (if (< n 2) 1 (+ (fibbd (- n 1)) (fibbd (- n 2)))))
#+end_src

#+name: fibbd
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var n=2 :results silent
(fibbd n)
#+end_src

| original | fibbd  |
|----------+--------|
|        0 | #ERROR |
|        1 | #ERROR |
|        2 | #ERROR |
|        3 | #ERROR |
|        4 | #ERROR |
|        5 | #ERROR |
|        6 | #ERROR |
|        7 | #ERROR |
|        8 | #ERROR |
|        9 | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-sbe "fibbd" (n $1))
```

As you can see I keep getting #ERROR
Am i doing something wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of changes needed to make it work. I've disabled evaluation confirmation in a file variable for convenience...

```
-*- mode: org; org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil; -*-

#+name: fibbd
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var n=0
(defun fibbd (n) (if (< n 2) 1 (+ (fibbd (- n 1)) (fibbd (- n 2)))))
(fibbd n)
#+end_src


| original | fibbd |
|----------+-------|
|        0 |     1 |
|        1 |     1 |
|        2 |     2 |
|        3 |     3 |
|        4 |     5 |
|        5 |     8 |
|        6 |    13 |
|        7 |    21 |
|        8 |    34 |
|        9 |    55 |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-sbe fibbd (n $1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ( and for the trick to disable confirmation). Unfortunately, your code still produces the same #ERROR

Comment: It was working for me but I think I evaluated the code block that declares fibbd with C-c C-c. If you do that it works. I've edited my answer with a working version. I'm not sure if there's a way to make the fibbd function get declared without somehow calling it explicitly